# Display all data in vertical format python csv

Tags: python, excel, csv

Hello guys i tried a lot of method displaying the below code. I wanted it to be displayed in another orientation.

This Code display the following excel file.

```
newDirRH = "C:/Plots"
newfile = newDirRH + "/TabulatedStatsVSM.csv"
with open(newfile, "wb") as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerow(["NameIP", "TypeIP", "FieldIP", "SignalIP", "NameOP", "TypeOP", "FieldOP", "SignalOP"])
    writer.writerow(["name","type","[cm]","[m]","name","type","[cm]","[m]"])
    for field, signal, field1, signal1 in zip(FieldIP, signalIP, FieldOP, signalOP):
        writer.writerow([NameIP, TypeIP,field, signal, NameOP, TypeOP,field1, signal1])
        NameIP = TypeIP = NameOP = TypeOP =  ''
```

Excel file displayed by the following code.

[image]

I am trying to achieve something like this. Is it possible??
This excel file, i edited myself.

[image]

Comment: @JohnJohn2 how to display like the below example?

Comment: Have you tried to rearrange the items in your code? It seems rearranging the fields will do

Comment: @sam092 yup i did, I tried putting \n to leave a spacing in excel but it keep giving me error ...

Comment: @ZhenHui show your code as well. we might be able to find bug in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem: There is no "\n" in writer.writerow thats is why you keep having error found. For csv you have to write a row at a time. The following code is what you want.

```
import csv

FieldIP = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
FieldOP = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
signalIP = [0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,0.10,0.11,0.12,0.13,0.14,0.15,0.16,0.17,0.18,0.19,0.20]
signalOP = [0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,0.10,0.11,0.12,0.13,0.14,0.15,0.16,0.17,0.18,0.19,0.20]
NameIP = "JDP123"
TypeIP = "ID123"
NameOP = "JDP124"
TypeOP = "ID124"

newDirRH = "C:/VSMPlots"
newfile = newDirRH + "/TabulatedStatsVSM1.csv"
with open(newfile, "wb") as csvfile:
writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
writer.writerow(["NameIP", "TypeIP", "NameOP", "TypeOP"])
writer.writerow([NameIP, TypeIP, NameOP, TypeOP])
writer.writerow([" "])
writer.writerow(["FieldIP", "SignalIP", "FieldOP", "SignalOP"])
for field, signal, field1, signal1 in zip(FieldIP, signalIP, FieldOP, signalOP):
    writer.writerow([field, signal, field1,signal1])
print "Done"
```

Answer (score 0):

write in writerow 1 at a time and you should be fine.

```
writer.writerow(["NameIP", "TypeIP", "NameOP", "TypeOP"])
writer.writerow([NameIP, TypeIP, NameOP, TypeOP])
writer.writerow([" "]) # Leaving a space accordng to your excel
writer.writerow(["FieldIP", "SignalIP", "FieldOP", "SignalOP"])
for field, signal, field1, signal1 in zip(FieldIP, signalIP, FieldOP, signalOP):
    writer.writerow([field, signal, field1,signal1])
```